# GDB error "cp_search_static_and_baseclasses"

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb

I'm using STM32 Workbench (Eclipse based IDE) and I have a workspace with a couple of C++ static libs and 2 C++ applications, all made with the STM32F4 MCU C++ application or static lib template.

My first application went well and I started the second. This project templates add a main.c with an inifinite loop, regardless of the language. If I try to debug the main.c everything is fine, but if I change the file name to main.cpp (I need that to use C++ classes inside) GDB stops before debug with the error:

> /home/build/work/GCC-5-0-build/src/gdb/gdb/cp-namespace.c:343:
>   internal-error: cp_search_static_and_baseclasses: Assertion
>   `name[prefix_len + 1] == ':'' failed.

Before that I alo have a lot of "No source file named" error for files that are just needed for my first application, even for the main.cpp of the first application.

I'm using Stm32 Workbench 1.9 in Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 with GDB 7.10.1

**EDIT**

I assumed that the "no source file named" error indicate that maybe GDB is being loaded with the wrong files so I tried to create a new workspace with just the projects needed for this application and everything works. Still, it would be nice to have all of the projects in the same workspace, I'm not sure if having lib projects opened in 2 workspaces can be harmful.

Comment: Get the latest version of gdb and try again. If it still occurs you might have found a bug. Try to track it down and file a bug-report - **but only after careful inspection and you are 100% sure the problem is gdb, not some library or anything else**.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem in Eclipse with GDB crashing. I had some old breakpoints active in the eclipse workspace. After removal of these breakpoints from other projects the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have information to contribute though not a full answer. I would add as a comment, but I don't have the rep. points yet to do so.

I am able to run to main, but when I set a breakpoint, I see the same behavior as the OP. My version of gdb is 7.11

I have noticed that if I ssh from the host to the target and start gdb, I do not observe the behavior--I can set breakpoints, no problem. I only see the bad behavior if I do this through Eclipse. The one difference between the 2 scenarios I see is that when gdb is started through Eclipse (via ssh), it uses the `--interpreter mi2` option.

Maybe this will trigger an idea for a work-around...

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled about this issue with an ST-LinkV2.

As silly as it sounds, the solution was to delete the break points at `main()` for all projects.